# Is there a function that executes sql? Specifically sql generated by the CakeSchema?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Is there a function that executes mysql? Specifically mysql generated by the CakeSchema?

This is an example of the data I want to import:

```
    $this->Schema = new CakeSchema();
    $Schema = $this->Schema->load();
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->Schema->connection);
    $contents = "\n\n" . $db->createSchema($Schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's actually MySQL, then just use query()

```
$this->MyModel->query("CREATE TABLE ....");
```

Because it likely doesn't really fit with one of your models, you can always make a "DataFunction" model and tell it to `$useTable = false;`... then store any/all of these kind of "general" functions there.  Then load the model and call your function from whatever action you'd like.

Comment: The import is for all db tables. Not just for one table/model. I wouldn't suspect $this-MyModel->query() would work as it only has one model defined, right?

Comment: alairock: it works.  It's just a way to run raw MySQL code - related to a model or not.

Comment: Works. It was dirtier than I was hoping for but it works. Donka!

Comment: edited - I believe you can use Model::query(), but where would you run it?  A Model is the part of MVC that accesses the database.  Doesn't seem dirty to me.  Make a "DataImport" model and tell it to `$useTable = false;`... then store any/all of these kind of "general" functions there.

Comment: Ironically this is exactly what I had already done. It doesn't feel as dirty when done like this. Agreed.